# Force a returned const value to move not copy

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I know that this is OK:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo& operator=( Foo& ) = delete; // disallow assign
    Foo( int ) { }                   // some basic constructor
    Foo( const Foo& ) = delete;      // disallow copy
    Foo( Foo&& ) { }                 // allow move
};

Foo getFoo( void ) {
    return Foo( 3 );
}
Foo foo = getFoo( ); // uses move constructor
```

whereas this is will use the copy constructor, and is therefore invalid for `Foo` (and for any object *with* a copy constructor, it will be valid but inefficient):

```
const Foo getConstFoo( void ) {
    return Foo( 3 );
}
const Foo constFoo = getConstFoo( ); // error: copy constructor is deleted!
```

but this is OK: (and will extend the life of `constFooRef`)

```
const Foo& constFooRef = getConstFoo( ); // uses move constructor
```

Now, the second case will call

```
Foo( const Foo&& ) { }
```

if it's available. So I would like to know if there's any way to detect that the final object will be `const` from inside that constructor. If there is, I can apply move semantics (since both involved objects are const and the parameter isn't being used elsewhere it's ok to cast away the const-ness), and make the second case legal.

So while my question title explains the end-result I'm trying to achieve, my sub-problem is detecting whether an object will be const after it has been constructed (naïvely I tried `Foo( const Foo&& ) const { }`, but no luck there!)

Comment: Just don't return `const`-values, period. Also, no, casting away `const`ness would invoke UB, since the object was originally declared as `const`.

Comment: @Xeo I need to return const values. The objects in question are images, which can return new image objects as windows to their own data. If the original object was `const`, the new object must also be `const`. Also, I thought undefined behaviour only appeared if the const object was in const memory, which means it would need to be a compile-time const (which I think isn't possible in this case but I could be wrong)

Comment: I'm failing to see why the *members* being const while the *objects* can be freely copied would *not* solve your problem. but its way late here, i should probably already be sawing logs.

Comment: @WhozCraig consider, `myConstImage.red( ).invert( )`. The returned object from `red` must be const to avoid this. And if I allowed free copying, `Image rchannel = myConstImage.red( )` would be possible. I only want to allow `const Image rchannel = myConstImage.red( )`.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure `Foo foo = getFoo();` uses move or copy constructor? It should just construct in-place, without any copying/moving. And, in any case, `Foo const foo = getFoo();` will get you a `const` object without any need for `getFoo()` to actually return a `const` object.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: it might not *call* the constructor due to copy/move elision, but it still "uses" it according to a technical definition that's important to the standard and hence also important to the compiler. Basically, a copy/move must be available even if it's going to be elided.

Comment: @Dave: this might not help you, but arguably if `View` is a view of some data, then a non-modifiable view of the data should be represented using a base class `NonModifyingView` of `View`, rather than using `const View`. Then you can return a non-const instance of `NonModifyingView`, and move that, and `image.red().invert()` is prevented by the fact that `NonModifyingView` simply doesn't have an `invert` function.

Comment: @SteveJessop +1 Thanks for the info, I never realized you still need to have them accessible even if they are eluded.

Comment: @SteveJessop I thought that might be the case, since I've seen that pattern in many places, but I don't see the advantage of it except in this specific case (which seems like it should have a solution!), and it complicates the API (not the logical `const Image` but instead `ConstImage`)

Comment: @dave: the disadvantage of what you want to do is that the constness is ambiguous -- is the view unmodifiable, or is the thing viewed unmodifiable? It is this ambiguity that's preventing you moving the const view object. You intend `const` to mean that the thing viewed cannot be modified, but what `const` *actually* means in the language is not that. So the advantage of introducing a new type is to resolve that ambiguity. What your abstraction almost (but sadly not quite) hides is the difference between a `const` pointer and pointer-to-const.

Comment: @SteveJessop I would argue that's not much of a disadvantage. While there are some optimisations to be had from const data, non-const view, they are quite minor. And it seems odd to say non-const data, const view (after all, internal optimisation means that the data might not even exist, or might point to another object, until after an operation is performed on it, which would necessitate updating the view). So the structure I'm aiming for is that const means both data and view are const, non-const means neither are const, and there are no other options.

Comment: @SteveJessop but I do understand that the language simply doesn't support that pattern.

Comment: @Dave: const data, non-const view is useful (probably only) if your type advertises to users the fact that it is an indirection. So `char const*` is a very useful type :-). I can believe that in your case this isn't very helpful! And yes, the limitation you're hitting is that the language doesn't let you return non-copyable, non-movable objects by value. Unless you violate the usual patterns for const-safety, const objects aren't movable (even to another const object). I assume you don't want your type to be copyable because that would expose the fact that it's an indirection?

Comment: @SteveJessop the issue with copying is that there's no "right choice" between A) making a new window to the data, and B) making a literal copy of the data. Implicit (A)-style copying would allow the user to get a non-const view of const data, which violates the pattern I'm going for, while implicit (B)-style copying would be a waste of CPU and memory. Currently my pattern is working except for this peculiarity with needing to assign const images by reference, which I can just about live with (after all, it's a compile-time issue not a runtime issue), but I thought I'd try to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

You might do

```
Foo::Constant getConstFoo( void ) {
    return Foo::Constant( 3 );
}
```

where Foo::Constant is immutable

```
struct Foo {
    struct Constant
    {
       Constant(Foo&&);
    };
    Foo& operator=( Foo& ) = delete; // disallow assign
    Foo( int ) { }                   // some basic constructor
    Foo( const Foo& ) = delete;      // disallow copy
    // You might not use: Foo( Foo&& ) { }                 // allow move
};
```

Comment: I don't understand; how would you use this? It sounds similar to Steve Jessop's suggestion, but having the `Constant` struct inside `Foo` surely removes all possibility for inheritance. Unless this is intended to be used in an entirely different way and I missed something?